# How To Configure Spring Websockets With CloudAMQP

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, spring-websocket, cloudamqp

I have a Spring Boot application which I am deploying to a Cloud Foundry instance (BlueMix).  I have bound a CloudAMQP instance to the application and would like to use it for sending my STOMP meessages.  I have not been able to properly configure my StompBrokerRelayRegistration class to successfully connect the RabbitMQ instance in CloudAMP.  I have called

```
config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue");
```

But this tried to connect to localhost.  I thought it might try to use my org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory bean but I guess not.

I then tried to call setRelayHost, setRelayPort, setSystemLogin, setSystemPasscode, and setVirtualHost with the information in VCAP_SERVICES.  After doing this Spring seems to try to connect to the RabbitMQ instance but based on the logs the connection is closed immediately saying

> Connection reset by peer

.  Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**Update**

Aparently I was using the wrong port.  Using port 5672 causes the behavior where the connection is closed immediately.  If I use port 61613 the connection appears to be established.  However once the browser tries to go and establish the websocket the following exception is thrown

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WebSocket session has been closed and no method (apart from close()) may be called on a closed session
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.checkState(WsSession.java:649)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.getUserPrincipal(WsSession.java:578)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.getPrincipal(StandardWebSocketSession.java:123)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.getPrincipal(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:73)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.afterSessionEnded(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:364)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.clearSession(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:352)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:347)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:71)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:89)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.close(AbstractSockJsSession.java:289)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketSessionDecorator.close(WebSocketSessionDecorator.java:158)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:287)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:306)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$1.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:70)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Above this I see this warning

```
2014-05-14T22:17:53.69-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2014-05-15 02:17:53.698  WARN 31 --- [tboundChannel-1] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Ignoring protocol in WebSocket session after failure to obtain it: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WebSocket session has been closed and no method (apart from close()) may be called on a closed session
2014-05-14T22:17:53.70-0400 [App/0]   OUT 2014-05-15 02:17:53.709 ERROR 31 --- [tboundChannel-1] w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator : Unhandled error for ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler@646eb571]]
```

Anyone have an idea on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Figured out what I was missing.  In addition to calling setSystemLogin and setSystemPasscode, I needed to call setClientLogin and setClientPasscode on StompBrokerRelayRegistration.  After doing this my WebSocket connection from the browser to the app on Cloud Foundry worked and Spring was able to use the RabbitMQ instance from CloudAMQP to send STOMP messages.